# Django: Error with inserting dictionary to my_model.objects.raw() method

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm performing a query in a function inside the views.py as follows:

```
input_dict = {'id': 'id',
              'table': 'my_table',
              'first_col': 'my_first_col',
              'first_name': 'my_first_name'}


query = '''
SELECT %(id)s
FROM %(table)s 
WHERE %(first_col)s = %(first_name)s '''


qs = my_model.objects.raw(query, input_dict)

print(qs)
```

which prints:

```
qs: <RawQuerySet: 
            SELECT id
            FROM my_table 
            WHERE my_first_col = my_first_name >
```

However, when I try to run this line:

```
ids = [item.id for item in qs]
```

it gives me an error:

```
psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "'my_table'"
LINE 3:             FROM 'my_table'
```

and also:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "'my_table'"
LINE 3:             FROM 'my_table'
```

What should I do?

Comment: You can't pass the table name as a parameter. There might be a safe solution, depending on which database you are using. For example, with PostgreSQL, you could use [`sql.SQL`](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html#module-psycopg2.sql).

Answer (score 0):

django are not able to excecut your query.

I believe what you trying to acheive via the raw function it is not possible.

read the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/ for better understanding how the function work

your dynamic options are realted either to the table fields and the where params:

1. the select fields

> you can map fields in the query to model fields using the translations
> argument to raw()

like :

```
name_map = {'first': 'first_name', 'last': 'last_name', 'bd': 'birth_date', 'pk': 'id'}
Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM some_other_table', translations=name_map)
```

2. the where params

> If you need to perform parameterized queries, you can use the params
> argument to raw()

```
lname = 'Doe'
Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person WHERE last_name = %s', [lname])
```

at the end of the day, this will work, although it's not recomended unless you know exactly what you are doing as it might expose your system to sql attacks

```
query = '''
SELECT %(id)s
FROM %(table)s 
WHERE %(first_col)s = %(first_name)s '''

query = query%input_dict

qs = my_model.objects.raw(query)
```